# Varying Coefficient Helmholtz Equation IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find an odd solution to:
$$u''(x) = V(x) u(x)$$

for $V(x)$ an even function. I propose the following IVP:

$$\partial_t \begin{pmatrix} u \\\ v \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\\ V(t) & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u_0 \\\ v_0 \end{pmatrix}$$

with
$$\begin{pmatrix} u_0 \\\ v_0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now we have:
$$\partial_t U = A(t) U(t)$$
And this can be solved as so:
$$e^{-\int_0^t A(s) ds} \partial_t U = -\left(\partial_t e^{-\int_0^t A(s) ds} \right) U$$
Giving us
$$\partial_t\left( e^{-\int_0^t A(s)  ds} U(t) \right) = 0$$
Hence,
$$e^{-\int_0^t A(s) ds} U(t) = U(0)$$
And we have the matrix $$e^{-\int_0^t A(s) ds}$$ is always invertible, giving us:
$$U(t) = e^{\int_0^t A(s) ds} U(0)$$

which can be solved by exponentiating the matrix:
$$M(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & t \\\ \int_0^t V(s) ds & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
using traditional methods.

If $V(t)$ is constant, this gives us the expected result. Should this approach work in general? What would the alternative approach for solving this for general $V$ be? I tried comparing results to numerical solutions, but they didn't seem to match.

Comment: Your solution to $\partial_t U = A(t) U(t)$ is not valid if $A(t_1)A(t_2)\neq A(t_2)A(t_1)$ for $t_1\neq t_2$. In this case, you should use the [Magnus expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\partial_t U(t)  = A(t) \ U(t) $$

means

$$U(t+dt) = U(t) + dt\ A(t)\ U(t) + o(dt^2)= (1 +dt \ A(t)) \  U(t)) + o(dt^2) $$

Reducing step size

$$t = n\  dt,  \  n\to \infty$$  we get

$$ U(t) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \prod_{k=n}^1 \left(1+\frac{t}{n} A\left(\frac{k}{n} t\right) \right)  \ne \exp{\int_0^t A(s)\ ds} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{\int_0^t A(s)\ ds}{n}\right)^n$$

because the product form of the "exponential" is a time ordered product, that is acted by $d U(t) \to A(t) U(t) dt$ on the left while the exponential of the integral is completely symmetric in all summands.

Sufficient for equality is that all $A(s)$  commute. Time ordering of the exponential produces the famous perturbation series in quantum physics, if the non commuting parts of the $A(s)$ for different times are small in a diagonal common basis representation.